# Read CSV file excluding first row

Tags: php, csv

> CSV format

```
"Type","Stock","VIN","Year"
"Used","5262G","1G1YY12S435101008","2003"
"Used","5539G","YV4902DZ2D2439476","2013"
"Used","15460","YV4612HK3F1000423","2015"
```

> My code to get the TYPE, STOCK, VIN, YEAR

```
$file = fopen("files/stillmanmvolvo.csv", "r");
echo "</br></br>";

while(! feof($file))
{
    $file_data = fgetcsv($file);

    $type                   = $file_data[0];
    $stock                  = $file_data[1];
    $vin                    = $file_data[2];
    $year                   = $file_data[3];

    echo $type .' '. $stock .' '. $vin .' '. $year . '<br><br>';
}
fclose($file);
```

> Output

```
Type Stock VIN Year

Used 5262G 1G1YY12S435101008 2003

Used 5539G YV4902DZ2D2439476 2013

Used 15460 YV4612HK3F1000423 2015
```

With the above code I am getting the data, but the data includes the first `ROW` ie, `"Type","Stock","VIN","Year"` (*please see first line in the output*)
I want to `exclude` the first row, what changes in my code need to do so that it exclude the first ROW..?

Thank you

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393295/best-way-to-skip-a-header-when-reading-in-from-a-text-file-in-perl

Comment: @lordkain - not a duplicate of that as this is PHP, and the link is for Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just reading the line into empty space to skip it :

```
$file = fopen("files/stillmanmvolvo.csv", "r");
echo "</br></br>";

// read first line
if(!feof($file)) { fgetcsv($file); }

// continue reading the rest of the file
while(! feof($file))
{
    $file_data = fgetcsv($file);

    $type                   = $file_data[0];
    $stock                  = $file_data[1];
    $vin                    = $file_data[2];
    $year                   = $file_data[3];

    echo $type .' '. $stock .' '. $vin .' '. $year . '<br><br>';
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: You are welcome Shan.  I encourage you to look at the other examples as well.  Someone mentioned using `fgets()` which would be a slight performance improvement when reading the first line to skip - if you are inclined to boost performance as much as possible :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$file_data = fgetcsv($file);// now the file pointer is on second row
while(! feof($file))
{    
    $file_data = fgetcsv($file);
    $type                   = $file_data[0];
    $stock                  = $file_data[1];
    $vin                    = $file_data[2];
    $year                   = $file_data[3];
    echo $type .' '. $stock .' '. $vin .' '. $year . '<br><br>';
}
```

Comment: having it inside the loop causes extra cpu cycles as the check is done on every iteration for the value of `$i`

Comment: voting everyone up who kept it out of the loop ^^.  it is a mistake that is all too common in programming, which end up being very costly (cumulative) in the long run.  tiny improvements like this (someone else mentioned using `fgets()` instead of using `fgetcsv` in the line being skipped.  I tossed in a `feof` check as well more for assurance there is actually data to read.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `fgets($file)` after `fopen()` but before the `while` loop

```
$file = fopen("files/stillmanmvolvo.csv", "r");
fgets($file)
echo "</br></br>";

while(! feof($file))
{
    $file_data = fgetcsv($file);

    $type                   = $file_data[0];
    $stock                  = $file_data[1];
    $vin                    = $file_data[2];
    $year                   = $file_data[3];

    echo $type .' '. $stock .' '. $vin .' '. $year . '<br><br>';
}
fclose($file);
```

[fgets() docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)

Comment: ^  this would work as well :)   slightly faster than reading `fgetcsv($file)` as in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$file = fopen("files/stillmanmvolvo.csv", "r");
$first = false;
echo "</br></br>";

while(! feof($file))
{
    $file_data = fgetcsv($file);
    if (!$first) {
        $first = true;
        continue;
    }

    $type                   = $file_data[0];
    $stock                  = $file_data[1];
    $vin                    = $file_data[2];
    $year                   = $file_data[3];

    echo $type .' '. $stock .' '. $vin .' '. $year . '<br><br>';
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: having it inside the loop causes extra cpu cycles as the check is done on every iteration for the value of `$first`